# jQuery: Giving each matched element an unique ID

Tags: jquery, unique, element, tree-traversal

I am writing an 'inline translator' application to be used with a cloud computing platform to extend non-supported languages. The majority of this uses jQuery to find the text value, replace it with the translation, then append the element with a span tag that has an unique ID, to be used elsewhere within the application.  The problem arises however, when there are more than one element, say , that have the exact same value to be translated (matched elements).  What happens in the function in question is that it puts all matched elements in the same span, taking the second, third, fourth, etc. out of their parent tags.  My code is pretty much like this example:

```
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
var uniqueID='asdfjkl';
jQuery(window).ready(function() {
var myQ1 = jQuery("input[id~=test1]");
myClone=myQ1.clone();
myClone.val('Replaced this button');
myQ1.replaceWith('<span id='+uniqueID+'></span>');
jQuery('#'+uniqueID).append(myClone);
});
</script>
<table>
<tr><td>
<input id='test1' type='button' value="I'm a button!"></input> &nbsp;
<input id='test2' type='button' value="And so am I"></input>
</tr></td>
<tr><td>
<input id='test1' type='button' value="I'm a button!"></input>
</tr></td>
</table>
```

As a workaround, I've experimented with using a loop to create a class for each span, rising in increment until jQuery("input[id~=test1]").length, but I can't seem to get anything I do to work.  Is there any way to give each matched element an unique ID?  My fluency in jQuery is being put to the test!

Thanks for any help in advance.

Aaron

Comment: Your original HTML is not valid.  You can't have two elements using the same id.  They can have the same name, but not the same id.

Answer (score 4):

My take was to generate a random number and append it to the initial id:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(window).ready(function() {

   var myQ1 = jQuery("input[id*='test']");
   var uniqueNum = Math.floor( Math.random()*99999 );
   var uniqueID = myQ1.attr('id')+'-'+String(uniqueNum);

   myClone=myQ1.clone();
   myClone.text('Replaced this button');

   myQ1.replaceWith('<span id='uniqueID+'></span>');

   jQuery('#'+uniqueID).append(myClone);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's good stuff, thanks to all!  In the end it looks like:

```
var myQ1 = jQuery("input[name~=test1]");
myQ1.each(function() {
    var id = Math.floor( Math.random()*99999 );
    jQuery(this).wrap("<span id=\"span-"+id+"\"></span>");
...
```

Aseptik, there is a lot more code, much more than I drug into this, so I wanted to keep the part I was hung up on brief.  Thanks again for the input.

Regards,
Aaron

Comment: The way to thank users on StackOverflow is to hit the up arrow next to their answer or accept it as the correct answer if you decide to use their code as part of your solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is wrap.  The following will wrap each element that contains `test` in the id with a span.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input[id*=test]").wrap('<span></span>');
});
```

Note that you can use the existing ids to match the span using a parent selector so there isn't really a need to duplicate it or generate one.

```
$("input[id*=test]').parent('span')...
```

If you really wanted to create new elements with ids, you could use each with some unique naming scheme.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input[id*=test]").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('id');
        $this.wrap('<span id="span-' + id + '"></span>");
    });
});
```